# How is HandlerFunc returned by function that should return Handler?

Tags: go

While chaining handlers, the function has a return type of Handler, but it actually returns a HandlerFunc. This does not throw any error.

How is HandlerFunc accepted in place of a Handler, the prior being a function type and the latter being a interface type?

```
func log(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ...
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The HandlerFunc type is an adapter to allow the use of  ordinary
>   functions as HTTP handlers. If f is a function  with the appropriate
>   signature, HandlerFunc(f) is a  Handler that calls f.

The `http.Handler` is an interface:

```
type Handler interface {
    ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)
}
```

The `http.HandlerFunc` is a type:

```
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)

// ServeHTTP calls f(w, r).
func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    f(w, r)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`http.Handler`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) is an interface. [`http.HandlerFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) is a concrete type that implements that interface. This is all documented in the [`http` package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http). If interfaces are new to you, start with [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9).